# kafka + how to revert topic deletion

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

just in case we delete the wrong topic as

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper hdpmaster01:2181 --delete --topic gtom.poli.pri.proc

Topic gtom.poli.pri.proc is already marked for deletion
```

Topic **gtom.poli.pri.procis** already marked for deletion
and now we want to revert it

what are the steps to revert topic deletion?

all folders topics as the following are still exists under

**/var/kafka/kafka-logs**

```
gtom.poli.pri.procis-23
gtom.poli.pri.procis-45
gtom.poli.pri.procis-34
.
.
.
```

Comment: Please don't spam random tags. This has nothing to do with Kafka consumer api, Hadoop, or Ambari

Comment: And if you never enabled topic deletion on the broker, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abort the deletion by running the following command in zookeeper:

```
rmr /admin/delete_topics/gtom.poli.pri.procis
```

Note that this will only prevent the deletion to proceed if it has not already started. If anything has already been deleted, it's gone